# Powercfg /requests shows a bunch of "[PROCESS] Legacy Kernel Caller" entries instead of real data when called from .bat file

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11, powercfg

To quickly view what's causing my monitor to not sleep, I usually use this .bat script with this simple contents:

```
@echo off
powercfg /requests
pause
```

On my Windows 10 machine, it results in the output one would expect, but when I try it on my Windows 11 machine (run .bat file as administrator), it shows a bunch of "[PROCESS] Legacy Kernel Caller" entries instead:

[image]

Here's the weird part - if I just open cmd as admin and type in `powercfg /requests`, it shows correct output:

[image]

So, what is going on here? Why is the output of the batch file full of garbage entries?

Comment: Better remove the `@echo off` in order to get a fuller output and add it to your port.

Comment: @harrymc There's no change if I remove it. No extra information is printed.

Comment: Next, [Create a Power Efficiency Diagnostics Report](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5148-create-power-efficiency-diagnostics-report-windows-10-a.html) and post the result HTML file online (OneDrive, Dropbox etc) for us.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work. Same issue as https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/powercfg-energy-not-working/633a90ed-1356-4d49-8a15-ca2aa8ef46b6. I run the command, it exits right away, and no file is created: https://i.imgur.com/6p4CIet.png.

Comment: Your Windows seems to be in a bad shape. I suggest doing [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html). This is the same as doing a major Windows upgrade, so take the same precautions.